# Layers with same coordinates not lining up - EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 - for Trentino in Italy

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, openstreetmap, coordinates, spatialite

It's been a while that I've been noticing that the layers don't line up with open street maps, although I've always been setting the same coordinate system.
The coordinate system is EPSG:4326 - WGS 84.
I tipically download all I need from the official sites of Autonomous Province of Trento in Italy; e.g. https://siat.provincia.tn.it/geonetwork/srv/ita/catalog.search;jsessionid=06CDDB43CA3115027C7C450F640B472E#/metadata/p_TN:f2e88f1b-05d9-4942-93ee-857a0a9e1f0b).
If I open the Open Street Maps, all the layers I import are located in the middle of the Mediterranean Sea (in particular they are always located off the Sardinian western coasts), instead of being located in Trentino (Italy).

What can I do?

[image]

Comment: Dont ever set the CRS of layers. Load them with their native CRS, QGIS will do the rest.

Comment: So the right way is to open my Web Map first and then import my files. This solved the problem for the ortophoto raster but not for the files downloaded from this links: https://idt.provincia.tn.it/idt/raster/lidar_2009_pat_dsm_1mX1m/ and https://idt.provincia.tn.it/idt/raster/lidar_2009_pat_dsm_2mX2m/. From default, my project has EPSG: 4326, the web maps have EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator. If I leave this settings, when I open the rasters (which are DSM tif files) the web map disappears; if I change the web maps system into 4326 and then load my dsm files, they set in the sea.